# Wisteria's trunk covered with soil

Tags: raised-beds, wisteria

I have built a raised bed around the wisteria and planning to fill it up with soil, but before I burry wisteria's trunk I just wanted to check if it'll cause any issues. I've seen some posts with reference to covering tree trunk with soil and it was considered a bad idea. If I should avoid it - any recommendation on how to make it work with it being within the boundaries of the raised bed?

[image]